# Condition variable never initialized/stuck in a deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

A while ago I tested out the way semaphores work with a simple program, where 3 threads (each called by its function) synchronize in a way that the output looks like:

```
<ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE>...
```

(code [here](https://pastebin.com/3Wihb5DM) for everyone interested or as a reference point)

I tried to recreate the very same program using condition variables and things got a *littly-bity* tricky.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


pthread_cond_t condvar1=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condvar2=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condvar3=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t MUT=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int loop=3;

void *one()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
        if(pthread_cond_signal(&condvar3)==0)
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condvar1, &MUT);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);

                printf("<ONE>");

        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);    
            pthread_cond_signal(&condvar2);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);
    }

    return(NULL);
}

void *two()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
        if(pthread_cond_signal(&condvar1)==0)  
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condvar2, &MUT);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);

                printf("<TWO>");

        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);    
            pthread_cond_signal(&condvar3);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);
    }

    return(NULL);
}

void *three()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
        if(pthread_cond_signal(&condvar2)==0)   
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condvar3, &MUT);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);

                printf("<THREE>");

        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);    
            pthread_cond_signal(&condvar1);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);
    }

    return(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t ena, dyo, tria;

    pthread_create(&ena, NULL, one, NULL);
    pthread_create(&dyo, NULL, two, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tria, NULL, three, NULL);

    pthread_join(ena, NULL);
    pthread_join(dyo, NULL);
    pthread_join(tria, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically I got a problem with initializing the first variable (condvar1) in order the synchronization to begin, since the hugely convenient `sem_init()` is out of the question.

Later I though that besides that, I could check if the *previous* condition variable (`if(pthread_cond_signal(&previousconditionvariable)==0)`) has released its lock or not and then I could lock the *next* condition variable.

But still, no proper initialization for condvar1 (for as much as I searched [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/apis/users_75.htm), [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/ptcaint.htm#ptcaint), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0630/6j9vkb8fr/index.html)) and of course no output.

Any ideas on initializing and/or tips for checking the previous' condition variable signal?

**UPDATE**: Removed the previous ifs and got a flag at their places like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


pthread_cond_t condvar1=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condvar2=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condvar3=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t MUT=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int flag;
int loop=3;

void *one()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
        if(flag==1)
        {
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condvar1, &MUT);
        }   
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);

                printf("<ONE>");
        flag=2;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);    
            pthread_cond_signal(&condvar2);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);
    }

    return(NULL);
}

void *two()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
        if(flag==2)  
        {
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condvar2, &MUT);

        }   
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);

                printf("<TWO>");
        flag=3;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);    
            pthread_cond_signal(&condvar3);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);
    }

    return(NULL);
}

void *three()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
        if(flag==3)  
        {
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condvar3, &MUT);

        }    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);

                printf("<THREE>");
        flag=1;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);    
            pthread_cond_signal(&condvar1);    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);
    }

    return(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t ena, dyo, tria;

    flag=1;

    pthread_create(&ena, NULL, one, NULL);
    pthread_create(&dyo, NULL, two, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tria, NULL, three, NULL);

    pthread_join(ena, NULL);
    pthread_join(dyo, NULL);
    pthread_join(tria, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

now the output is `<THREE><THREE><THREE><TWO><TWO><TWO><ONE><ONE><ONE>`

Comment: "*`if(pthread_cond_signal(&previousconditionvariable)==0`*": docs are here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html

Comment: Confused, should I use "pthread_cond_broadcast()" instead?

Comment: Stop thinking of condition variables as "state"; *that isn't what they're for*. They're a *signaling* mechanism. They communicate to those that are listening of *potential* change in some predicate state (which is the purpose of the mutex; to protect the predicate data during examination and updating; it has *nothing* to do with protecting the condition variable). Basically your code has no predicate.

Comment: I'm a day into condition variables so excuse me for misunderstanding their use. should i use a boolean variable for all the threads? should i use a while loop instead of an if statement?

Comment: Your revised code doesn't print the results in a deterministic order: I got `<THREE><TWO><ONE><ONE><ONE><TWO><TWO><THREE><THREE>` and `<TWO><THREE><TWO><THREE><TWO><ONE><THREE><ONE><ONE>` on successive runs, for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Leffler This is weird. I ran it at an old version of xubuntu inside a virtual machine, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm running it on a 2016 MacBook Pro under macOS Sierra 10.12.4.  It's an Intel Core i7 chip with 4 cores.

Comment: I guess I'm at the wrong side here, then. Do you have any idea about how to fix the synchronization?

Comment: Also in this case you might as well just lock the mutex before the `for` loop and unlock after... unlocking during the loop body is unnecessary since only one thread should be doing anything (besides waiting) at any time, and the threads will release the mutex during the condition wait anyway.

Comment: `if(flag==1)` --> `if(flag!=1)` etc.

Comment: If you haven’t already, you might want to do it with an `atomic_int` next. Much more efficient on most computers, because most architectures make it lock-free, and in the standard library!

Comment: @Dmitri your comment seemed to work, thank you very much, would you like to post it as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

This code is a simplification of your code, and I believe it works as desired.  There's a single thread function which is controlled by its argument.  There's only one condition variable, too.  The `turn` variable dictates which thread's turn it is.  The manipulation of the `turn` is done while the thread has the mutex locked, so no other thread is playing with it at the same time.  The printing is likewise done while the mutex is locked, to ensure it occurs at the correct time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_cond_t condvar = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t MUT = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

static int turn;
static int loop = 3;

struct Control
{
    int thread_num;
    const char *msg;
};

static void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    struct Control *ctl = arg;
    printf("Thread %d (%s)\n", ctl->thread_num, ctl->msg);

    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
        while (turn != ctl->thread_num)
            pthread_cond_wait(&condvar, &MUT);

        printf("<%s>", ctl->msg);
        turn++;
        if (turn > 3)
            turn = 1;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&condvar);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);
    }

    return(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t ena, dyo, tri;
    struct Control ctl[] =
    {
        { 1, "ONE"   },
        { 2, "TWO"   },
        { 3, "THREE" },
    };

    srand(time(0));
    turn = rand() % 3 + 1;
    printf("%d goes first\n", turn);

    pthread_create(&ena, NULL, thread_func, &ctl[0]);
    pthread_create(&dyo, NULL, thread_func, &ctl[1]);
    pthread_create(&tri, NULL, thread_func, &ctl[2]);

    pthread_join(ena, NULL);
    pthread_join(dyo, NULL);
    pthread_join(tri, NULL);

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

On my MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (using GCC 7.1.0, not that the compiler is all that important here), I get results such as this from consecutive runs (but there were indeterminate multi-second gaps between the runs):

```
2 goes first
Thread 1 (ONE)
Thread 2 (TWO)
Thread 3 (THREE)
<TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE>

3 goes first
Thread 1 (ONE)
Thread 2 (TWO)
Thread 3 (THREE)
<THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO>

3 goes first
Thread 1 (ONE)
Thread 2 (TWO)
Thread 3 (THREE)
<THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO>

1 goes first
Thread 1 (ONE)
Thread 2 (TWO)
Thread 3 (THREE)
<ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE>

3 goes first
Thread 2 (TWO)
Thread 1 (ONE)
Thread 3 (THREE)
<THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO><THREE><ONE><TWO>
```

Note that one time, thread 2 reported before thread 1.

I expect it would be possible to use three condition variables as in your original code, but it seems like overkill.

The error checking on the pthread calls is … non-existent.  That's sort-of-OK in example code, at least when it's working, but not a good idea in general.